# Output form ArrayMap equals to null

Tags: android, data-structures, array-map

I'm writing a parser to print a file json on my mobile. I include an ArrayMap to save data received from the file. My problem is that when I have to print data in a TextView, it returns null. I included the code under my question.

```
ArrayMap<Integer, String> Array = new ArrayMap<>();
for(int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    Array.put("Main", jsonPart.getString("main"));
    Array.put("Description", jsonPart.getString("description"));
    Array.put("Id", jsonPart.getString("id"));
    TxT.append(Txt.getText() + Array.get(i));
}
```

Comment: can you post your full code  where you have defined your arrayMap?

Comment: `ArrayMap<Integer, String> Array = new ArrayMap<>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not use the key word Array as it is preserve word, you can change it to something like jsonMap.
You should use `ArrayMap<String, String>` if you inserting String in the key element. 
So your code will look like this:

```
 ArrayMap<String, String> jsonMap = new ArrayMap<>();
 for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){
      JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
      jsonMap.put("Main", jsonPart.getString("main"));
      jsonMap.put("Description", jsonPart.getString("description"));
      jsonMap.put("Id", jsonPart.getString("id"));
      TxT.append(TxT.getText() + jsonMap.get(i));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Changed your arraymap declaration like this

```
ArrayMap<String,String>Array = new ArrayMap<>();
```